# Swift Local notification not firing

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to fire a local notification in my ios App.

```
let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
notificationContent.title = "Test"
notificationContent.body = alert            
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: notificationContent, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }else{
                    print("local push scheduled!")
                }
            })
```

When I try to run it, local notification it's correctly scheduled but never fired...some help?

Comment: Have you requested authorisation to send notifications to the user?

Comment: yes i did:[.badge, .alert, .sound]

Comment: Okay, and in the settings it is saying that notifications are allowed?

Comment: yes of course notification are enabled for my app

Comment: There’s no “of course” here, something isn’t working properly and I’m ruling out all possibilities starting at the most simple possible solutions. When do you fire the notification, while the app is in the foreground or background?

Comment: Increase time interval then run a project and go minimise it

Comment: I increased time intervall ti 5 secondos but nothing happened...

Comment: Kane what does mean "fire the notification"? i only schedule it (after 5 seconds for example) and it will fired after 5 seconds i hope

Comment: timeInterval has to be 60 or more seconds for local notifications to work.

Answer (score 3):

The time (in seconds) that must elapse before the trigger fires. This value must be greater than zero.

A new time interval trigger based on the specified temporal information. If repeats is true, the value in the timeInterval parameter must be 60 seconds or greater.

Comment: I believe you are getting silenced notifications if your app is running. Try to increase the timeInterval and send your app to the background before alert is expected. You can also use some UserNotificationDelegate methods, to handle notifications in the foreground.

Comment: So that's why my notifications were only firing when I was messing with the date in settings (the app was in background then). I thought something else was wrong and they weren't working. Thanks for explaining.